# Has alternative for looper.quitSafely() in below android api 17?

Tags: android, handler, looper

Is there a alternative way for `looper.quitSafely()` in below android API 17 ?

Comment: yes, `Looper#quit()`

Comment: No, the Looper#quit()  close looper immediate and not run enqueue messages, I need stop looper after all message handled.

Comment: this is the only thing you can do

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not below API 17. It's below 18.

Second, there is a way:

```
private val backgroundHandler: Handler
private val backgroundHandlerThread = HandlerThread("ICEManagerWrapper")

fun stop() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        backgroundHandlerThread.quitSafely()
    else
        backgroundHandler.post {
            backgroundHandlerThread.quit()
        }
}
```